# Solve the system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the system:
$2x+y=C$;
$3y+z=C$;
$x-4z=C$ 
Where $C$ is a constant. Find the smallest positive integer $C$ such that $x,y$ and $z$ are all integers.

My idea was to do this using trial and error by assigning values to $C$ (starting from 0 and going up) and seeing if that works. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint. By solving the linear system we can easily find that
$$(x,y,z)=\frac{C}{23}(7,9,-4).$$